# Generating a list from Database of Objects

Tags: java, android, database, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm kinda new to Android Programming. I'm trying to create a list of several objects. Each list item should look like this:

```
 _________________________________________
| Title Text View           | Edit |Delete|
| Secondary Title Text View |Button|Button|
```

Each list item represent an object which was read from a database. My question is, how do I keep the list dynamic according to additions, edits and deletes, which the user can perform?
I thought about reading the database into an array and then using array adpater, and when the programs finishes, writing it back into the database, but I cannot match the objects' fields into each text view (or atleast I don't know how).
I'm sorry if my question seems stupid, I'm really new to android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is create an adapter which holds the data that you got from the DB.

The data will be displayed using a ListView (this is the part that will display your attached sketch).

After you change the data in the DB, you should refresh the adapter using:

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So your ListView will reflect the changes.